# Should the [store] tag be burninated?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

The [store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/store) tag seems to be used for tagging a whole bunch of unrelated questions. moreover its WIKI excerpt describes it as related to data stores.

Maybe it deserves to be burninated, since there are more specific tags for data stores and its general meaning as an English word is too broad to be useful for tagging.

Comment: 1700 questions tagged, 15 followers. [Most questions go in combination with ExtJs](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/206651/questions-tagged-store?tagname=store) but beyond that there isn't much correlation...

Comment: The title would be awesome if you said: Should the [store] be burn?

Comment: @Braiam You mean something along [these lines](http://youtu.be/EBjuoMy9FUU)? :-D

Answer (score 3):

A low-rep user is now removing the "store" tag from a bunch of questions. Better would be to add the appropriate tag the user actually meant (for instance google-play, app-store, windows-store-apps).

And either burninate it without bumping all those old questions or have a high-rep user do it so it's not wasting review time.

Comment: If the edits get rejected, the low-rep user will be review-banned and will stop clogging the review queue.

Comment: @MatthieuM. maybe he is sincerely trying to clean that mess up (sometimes his edits are substantive, sometimes he simply strips that tag off - which would be ok if the questions to address were less). IMHO it would be better if someone with mod privileges writes him a private message to stop doing that and burninates the tag as well.

Comment: @LorenzoDonati: I am not saying he is not acting in good faith (I did not check), just that its stream of edits will die naturally after getting rejected a couple times for not being substantive enough. In general, burnitate requests should not be pursued by low-rep users for this reason.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Fair Point, indeed.